# best practice to do line breaks in HTML with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need do a line break, but I don't want be using `<br>` tags over my html.

so I tried use : `<div class="clearfix"></div>`

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/#clearfix

but did not work.

basicly I just want a empty line to separate my divs.

e.g.:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="button" ng-show="versions" class="btn">
      copy link<i class="fa-link"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="button" ng-show="versions" class="btn">
      copy link<i class="fa-link"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Can you just use CSS spacing//margin to increase the space between the divs?

Comment: "I want an empty line but I don't want to use the tag that means empty line"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use bottom margin...that's what it's for.

```
.col-md-12 {
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
```

```css
.col-md-12 {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-12">
  <button type="button" ng-show="versions" class="btn">
    copy link<i class="fa fa-link"></i>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <button type="button" ng-show="versions" class="btn">
    copy link<i class="fa fa-link"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```